# Computing all possible two-way interaction terms in tidymodels

Tags: r, machine-learning, caret, tidymodels

I have been testing the Caret and the Tidymodels packages, trying to reproduce each other's results.
So far for interaction-free models I have been able to reproduce results, such as same hyperparameter tuning. Turns out Caret and Rsample even if set to the same seed will construct different sets when perfoming cross-validation. I have solved that so far thanks to other post here in stackoverflow.

```
### Create Folds
set.seed(123)
train_index <- createDataPartition(mtcars$mpg, p = 0.8, list = FALSE)
train <- mtcars[train_index, ]
test <- mtcars[-train_index, ]

# Create model in Caret
set.seed(123)
my_grid = 10^seq(-5,5,length.out=1000)
model_caret <- train(mpg ~ ., data = train,
                     method = "glmnet",
                     trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5),
                     preProcess=c("center","scale"),
                     tuneGrid=expand.grid(alpha=1,lambda=my_grid))
model_caret
cat("The final values used for the model were alpha = 1 and lambda
 = 0.06979814.")

### Create the same folds as in Caret
rsplit <- map2(model_caret$control$index,
               model_caret$control$indexOut,
               function(x,y) list(analysis = x, assessment = y))

splits <- lapply(rsplit, make_splits, data = train)
splits <- manual_rset(splits, names(splits))

### Create Model
my_model = linear_reg(mode = "regression",
                      engine = "glmnet",
                      penalty = tune(),
                      mixture = 1)

# Create recipe
my_recipe <- recipe(mpg ~ ., data = train) %>%
  step_normalize(all_predictors())

### Create Grid
my_grid = tibble(penalty=10^seq(-5,5,length.out=1000))

#### Create Workflow
my_wf = workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(my_recipe) %>% 
  add_model(my_model)

### Tuning hyperparameter
model_tuning = tune_grid(my_wf,resamples = splits,grid = my_grid)

### Show Best
model_tuning %>% select_best("rmse")
cat("Penalty is 0.0698")
```

However when it comes to models containng interaction terms, my efforts have been proved not enough. Since I have not been able to reproduce each other's results.

Go sample Code

So my question more precisely is, how can I compute all possible interaction terms in tidymodels using the step_interact() function to get the same results as in Caret.

```
### Create Folds
set.seed(123)
train_index <- createDataPartition(mtcars$mpg, p = 0.8, list = FALSE)
train <- mtcars[train_index, ]
test <- mtcars[-train_index, ]

# Create model in Caret
set.seed(123)
my_grid = 10^seq(-5,5,length.out=1000)
model_caret <- train(mpg ~ .^2, data = train,
                     method = "glmnet",
                     trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5),
                     preProcess=c("center","scale"),
                     tuneGrid=expand.grid(alpha=1,lambda=my_grid))
model_caret
cat("The final values used for the model were alpha = 1 and lambda
 = 0.9014776")

### Create the same folds as in Caret
rsplit <- map2(model_caret$control$index,
               model_caret$control$indexOut,
               function(x,y) list(analysis = x, assessment = y))

splits <- lapply(rsplit, make_splits, data = train)
splits <- manual_rset(splits, names(splits))

### Create Model
my_model = linear_reg(mode = "regression",
                      engine = "glmnet",
                      penalty = tune(),
                      mixture = 1)

# Create recipe
my_recipe <- recipe(mpg ~ ., data = train) %>%
  step_normalize(all_predictors()) %>% 
  step_interact(terms = ~.^2)

### Create Grid
my_grid = tibble(penalty=10^seq(-5,5,length.out=1000))

#### Create Workflow
my_wf = workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(my_recipe) %>% 
  add_model(my_model)

### Tuning hyperparameter
model_tuning = tune_grid(my_wf,resamples = splits,grid = my_grid)

### Show Best
model_tuning %>% select_best("rmse")

cat("penalty is 0.518 ")
```

Comment: Please don't include code like `rm(list = ls())` in your questions unless it's part of the problem - no one wants to accidentally run that while working on an answer and lose what they were working on.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the main issue is that your preprocessing stage is happening at "different times" across your two models.

In Caret, you are essentially creating a new dataset including all of your variables in your equation as well as the interaction terms, and then preprocessing, whereas in tidymodels you are doing the opposite.

If you want to replicate the behavior, I believe it's as simple as adjusting your recipe to:

```
my_recipe <- recipe(mpg ~ ., data = train) %>%
step_interact(terms = ~.^2) %>% 
step_normalize(all_predictors())
```

I need to check with a working example to be sure, so I will try to run a simple example to verify tonight.

Actually - re-reading your model, you are still okay.
~~edit: as topepo pointed out, you are missing one more term needed to replicate the behavior. `.^2` is the standard way to include all pairwise interactions, but it does not include actual squared terms.

to check for yourself,

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

dat = data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,1,1), x2 = c(1,2,1,18,1,2,1,2), y = c(8.9,7.9,6.1,5.1,4.2,1,1,10))
lm(data = dat, y~(x + x2)^2) %>% summary() %>% tidy()
```

You'll see that the linear model only includes x, x1 and x:x1. You should include the squared terms as well.~~

Comment: There is also `step_interact(terms = ~ all_numeric_predictors():all_numeric_predictors())`